# Using subqueries to show multiple answers which have this same value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to show this products which has the highest prize (group by manufacturer). But if two products has this same prize, SQL shows me one of them.

```
SELECT name, manufacturer, MAX(prize)
FROM products p
GROUP BY manufacturer
HAVING MAX(prize) = (SELECT MAX(p1.prize)
                  FROM products p1
                  WHERE p.manufacturer = p1.manufacturer
                  LIMIT 1
                 );
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a simple subquery -- no aggregation in the outer query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
WHERE p.prize = (SELECT MAX(p2.prize)
                 FROM products p2
                 WHERE p2.manufacturer = p.manufacturer
                );
```

As mentioned in your previous question, your use of `GROUP BY` is not correct.  You have unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.

Your use of aggregation in the outer query is why you are getting only one row per manufacturer.

In terms of performance, this is often the fastest method -- with the right indexes.  In this case, the right index is on `(manufacturer, prize)`.

Answer (score 1):

First select all the max prizes group by maufacturer and join to the main table:

```
select p.* from
(select manufacturer, MAX(prize) AS maxprize from products GROUP BY manufacturer) AS m
inner join products p
on m.manufacturer = p.manufacturer and m.maxprize = p.prize
order by p.manufacturer, p.name
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oVYBHyR2corsnHiiZGm5Jc/0)